# Extract nested data in BS4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the following HTML file and I would like to extract the runtime and views data params. I have been able to navigate to the main id=videouser class but I'm not sure how to now get the associated text..

```
vid_data = (soup('td', {'id':'videoUser'}))[0]

<td id="videoUser">
<div class="item" style="padding-left: 0;">
<span>Added by</span>
<a href="/user/glanceweb">glanceweb</a>
<a class="hint" hint="Send private message" href="#" onclick="return openPm('glanceweb')" overicon="iconMailOver">
<div class="icon iconMail di" style="margin-bottom:-1px"></div>
</a>
<span class="hint" hint="2013-04-01 01:07:00 UTC">10 months ago</span>
</div>
<div class="item"><span>Runtime:</span> 02:39</div>
<div class="item"><span>Views:</span> 284,397</div>
</td>
```

Would anyone know how to do this in BS4..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for all the text that is printed by the above HTML, this should do it:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(<your-html>)
div = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'item'})[0]
user = str(div.find_all('span')[0].string) + ' ' + str(div.find_all('a')[0].string) + ' ' + str(div.find_all('span')[1].string)
r_div = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'item'})[1]
runtime = r_div.get_text()
v_div = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'item'})[2]
views = v_div.get_text()
```

user would then have:

```
Added by glanceweb 10 months ago
```

runtime would then have:

```
Runtime: 02:39
```

views would then have

```
Views: 284,397
```